# How to groupby and update values in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas DataFrame` that looks similar to the following...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'col1':['A','C','B','A','B','C','A'],
...     'col2':[np.nan,1.,np.nan,1.,1.,np.nan,np.nan],
...     'col3':[0,1,9,4,2,3,5],
...     })
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    A   NaN     0
1    C   1.0     1
2    B   NaN     9
3    A   1.0     4
4    B   1.0     2
5    C   NaN     3
6    A   NaN     5
```

What I would like to do is group the rows of `col1` by value and then update any `NaN` values in `col2` to increment in value by 1 based on the last highest value of that group in col1.

So that my expected results would look like the following...

```
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    A   1.0     4
1    A   2.0     0
2    A   3.0     5
3    B   1.0     2
4    B   2.0     9
5    C   1.0     1
6    C   2.0     3
```

I believe I can use something like `groupby` on `col1` though I'm unsure how to increment the value in `col2` based on the last highest value of the group from `col1`. I've tried the following, but instead of incrementing the value of `col1` it updates the value to all `1.0` and adds an additional column...

```
>>> df1 = df.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).agg({'col2': 'min'})
>>> df = pd.merge(df1, df, how='left', left_on=['col1'], right_on=['col1'])
>>> df
  col1  col2_x  col2_y  col3
0    A     1.0     NaN     0
1    A     1.0     1.0     1
2    A     1.0     NaN     5
3    B     1.0     NaN     9
4    B     1.0     1.0     4
5    C     1.0     1.0     2
6    C     1.0     NaN     3
```

Comment: are the `1`'s in `col2` always placed at the beginning of the group?

Comment: `col3` in your expected output should change as you are sorting on `col1` ..No?

Comment: @jezrael umm.. little confused.. i think both

Comment: Expected output does not make sense. How did the order of  `col1` change, but the corresponding values in `col3` did not change in order?

Comment: @QuangHoang - in this case yes. The lowest number should always be placed at the beginning of the group.

Comment: @jezrael - yes, there will be multiple missing values in each group. col1 order should change to asc order from lowest to highest for each group.

Comment: @anky_91 - theoretically yes, but since I manually generated this "preferred outcome" I didn't change it. I'll update the comment to reflect that change as well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Erfan - see my comment above in regards to col3 and manually generating the preferred outcome. Edited the question to reflect changes.

Comment: @jezrael - sure, edited.

Comment: @jezrael - there will be multiple, i.e, 1000's per group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197882/discussion-between-jezrael-and-marrowgari).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) only for rows with missing values, add maximum value per group with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `max` and last replace by original values by `fillna`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['A','C','B','A','B','B','B'],
     'col2':[np.nan,1.,np.nan,1.,3.,np.nan, 0],
     'col3':[0,1,9,4,2,3,4],
     })
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
0    A   NaN     0
1    C   1.0     1
2    B   NaN     9
3    A   1.0     4
4    B   3.0     2
5    B   NaN     3
6    B   0.0     4

df = df.sort_values(['col1','col2'], na_position='last')
s = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('max')
df['new'] = (df[df['col2'].isna()]
                   .groupby('col1')
                   .cumcount()
                   .add(1)
                   .add(s)
                   .fillna(df['col2']).astype(int))


print (df)
  col1  col2  col3  new
3    A   1.0     4    1
0    A   NaN     0    2
6    B   0.0     4    0
4    B   3.0     2    3
2    B   NaN     9    4
5    B   NaN     3    5
1    C   1.0     1    1
```

Comment: legendary! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
df['col2_new'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(np.nan, x.value_counts().index[0]+1))
df = df.sort_values('col1')
```